# Gradle not provide dependency in subprojects

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, multi-module

I have a dependency problem in a gradle project and I do not know how to solve it.

I have a root project "project-root" and two subprojects "project-sub-a" and "project-sub-b".
The "project-sub-a" has a dependency from "project-sub-b".

**The structure is:**

```
project-root
|-settings.gradle
|-build.gradle
project-sub-a
|-build.gradle
project-sub-b
```

**project-root:settings.gradle:**

```
include 'project-sub-a', 'project-sub-b'
```

**project-root:build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin
        compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
        implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.3'
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.2.6.RELEASE")
        }
    }
}
```

**project-sub-a:build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':connection-service-common')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

After `./gradlew build` i get the following errors:

```
> Task :project-sub-b:compileJava
.../Pojo.java: error: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not exist
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

and more ...
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your are missing:

```
 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.3'
```

which (and a few other jackson jars) is a transitive dependency of

```
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

That is why project a does not complain. Because of that there is no need to put jackson in `subprojects`. Subproject a is getting it anyway.

Comment: Thanks. Now it works! I removed the 'implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.3'' from project-root:build.gradle and i moved the 'implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'' from project-sub-a:build.gradle to project-root:build.gradle.
But i still not understands why it not worked before. Maybe the 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.10.3' was wrong.